pytest rerunfailures doesn't always rerun failed tests
I'm running my tests from local and from cloudbuild setup with following plugins:
plugins: rerunfailures-14.0, allure-pytest-2.13.5, xdist-3.6.1
My requirement: I am running my tests in parallel using pytest-xdist. During the test execution, I sometimes get an AssertionError incorrectly due to service instance not being up at the time of test execution. So in those cases I want my test to be rerun. For this I'm using pytest-rerunfailures.
Issue: While the code itself works and tests are run fine, the failed tests don't get rerun at times (see attached screenshots) even when there are failures I've specifically asked for it to rerun. I am not able to pinpoint as to why the tests are not rerun in one instance of the execution versus the other.


Questions:

I do not see any relevant discussion on this topic. The execution command looks okay to me. I'm assuming I'm missing something basic. Can you point that out if that's true?
Are there any conflicts with the versions of plugins pytest-xdist and pytest-rerunfailures that I don't know about? (I don't believe there are.)
Am I using the placement of params incorrectly?
is xdist's -n logical the reason why the tests are not being rerun?

Command for local execution:
pytest -m smoke -v --user-id aaa --session-id bbb --tenant-id ccc --client-id ddd --version-name eee --env fff --alluredir=allure-results -n logical --reruns 3 --reruns-delay 5 --only-rerun TypeError --only-rerun AssertionError --maxfail 20

Cloudbuild build step:
# Run Tests
- name: 'gcr.io/my-project/python-allure:slim'
  id: 'run_tests'
  secretEnv: ['CLIENT_ID', 'USER_ID', 'TENANT_ID', 'SESSION_ID']
  env:
    - 'VERSION=${_VERSION}'
    - 'ENV=${_ENV}'
  entrypoint: 'bash'
  args:
    - '-c'
    - |
      pytest -m smoke -v --user-id $$USER_ID --session-id $$SESSION_ID \
        --tenant-id $$TENANT_ID --client-id $$CLIENT_ID --version-name $$VERSION \
        --env $$ENV --alluredir=allure-results -n logical --reruns 3 --reruns-delay 5 \
        --only-rerun TypeError --only-rerun AssertionError --maxfail 20 || echo "fail" > /workspace/build-status.txt

Note: Not sure if it's relevant but on the cloudbuild server, two workers are used with the above command.
Since this issue happens because of cold start by GCP, I have run the tests at odd times when there was no traffic and no service instances were available. The issue is not reproducible whenever I want. Sometimes the tests are rerun and other times they aren't.
I also have tried using -n auto and -n 2 options for running the tests in parallel but it's inconclusive for me since the nature of this issue is random. Any suggestions will be helpful here.
